# Adding legend to CorePlot slice

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, legend

I would like to be able to add a legend to a graph slice. How can I do this?

I tried to implement the following two methods but I don't think is right;

```
- (NSString *) legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart
                          recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{
    return @"Legend";
}

- (NSAttributedString *) attributedLegendTitleForPieChart:      (CPTPieChart *)     pieChart
                                              recordIndex:      (NSUInteger)    idxv{

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed"];
}
```

Here is the official CorePlot protocol documentation:

https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_pie_chart_data_source-p.html#a6a85e1a9e613eb65267abfb8a884434a

[image]

---

**EDIT: my code**

```
// .h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<CPTPlotSpaceDelegate,CPTPieChartDelegate,CPTLegendDelegate,CPTPlotDataSource>

- (void) initializeAll;
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil data:(NSMutableArray*)dataPoints;

 // .m

#import “MyViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView * pieChartgraphHostView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CPTGraph* pieChartGraph;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CPTPieChart* pieChart;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize data;

@synthesize pieChart, pieChartGraph;


- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil data:(NSMutableArray*)dataPoints{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.data = dataPoints;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self initializeGraph];
    [self updateViewData];
    [self configureChart];
}

- (void) initializeGraph{
    if (self.data == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error, should not use this without assigning data");
    }

    // Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
    self.graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHostView.bounds];
    self.graphHostView.hostedGraph = self.graph;
    ////////////////////


    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;

    // Axes
    // Label x axis with a fixed interval policy
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.separateLayers              = NO;
    x.title                       = @"X Axis";
    x.titleTextStyle              = titleStyle;
    x.delegate                    = self;


    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.separateLayers        = YES;
    y.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                            [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:0],
                            [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:300],
                            nil];

    y.title                 = @"Y Axis";
    y.titleTextStyle        = titleStyle;
    y.delegate              = self;


    CPTFill *whitebandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
    CPTFill *greenbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
    CPTFill *redbandFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[[CPTColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75]];

    [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0)] fill:whitebandFill]];
    [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(500.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0)] fill:greenbandFill]];

    [y addBackgroundLimitBand:[CPTLimitBand limitBandWithRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocationDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(750.0) lengthDecimal:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1024.0)] fill:redbandFill]];

    // Add the y2 axis to the axis set
    self.graph.axisSet.axes = @[x, y];


    /////////////////////
    // Get the (default) plotspace from the graph so we can set its x/y ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // Note that these CPTPlotRange are defined by START and LENGTH (not START and END) !!

    [plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1024]]];

    NSLog(@"creating x range for %lu data points", (unsigned long)[self.data count]);
    [plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.data count]]]];

    // Create the plot (we do not define actual x/y values yet, these will be supplied by the datasource...)
    self.plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


    // Let's keep it simple and let this class act as datasource (therefore we implemtn <CPTPlotDataSource>)
    self.plot.dataSource = self;
    self.plot.delegate = self;

    // Finally, add the created plot to the default plot space of the CPTGraph object we created before
    [self.graph addPlot:self.plot toPlotSpace:self.graph.defaultPlotSpace];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void)configureChart {
    // 1 - Get reference to graph

    pieChartGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds];
    self.pieChartgraphHostView.hostedGraph = pieChartGraph;
    pieChartGraph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    pieChartGraph.axisSet = nil;
    pieChart.title = @"My pie chart";

    // 2 - Create chart
    pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    pieChart.dataSource = self;
    pieChart.delegate = self;
    pieChart.pieRadius = (self.pieChartgraphHostView.bounds.size.height * 0.9) / 2;

    pieChartGraph.delegate = self;

    pieChart.identifier = pieChartGraph.title;
    pieChart.startAngle = CPTFloat(M_PI_4);
    pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
    pieChart.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    // 3 - Create gradient

    CPTGradient *overlayGradient = [[CPTGradient alloc] init];
    overlayGradient.gradientType = CPTGradientTypeRadial;
    overlayGradient = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0] atPosition:0.9];
    overlayGradient = [overlayGradient addColorStop:[[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4] atPosition:1.0];
    pieChart.overlayFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:overlayGradient];

    // 4 - Add chart to graph
    pieChart.pieRadius = pieChart.pieRadius / 2.3;
    [pieChartGraph addPlot:pieChart];

    self.dataForChart = [@[@20.0, @30.0, @25.0, @25.0] mutableCopy];
}

-(void)setRoundedView:(UIView *)roundedView toDiameter:(float)newSize;
{
    CGPoint saveCenter = roundedView.center;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
    roundedView.frame = newFrame;
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
    roundedView.center = saveCenter;
}


-(void)configureLegend {
    // 1 - Get graph instance
    CPTGraph *graph = self.graphHostView.hostedGraph;
    // 2 - Create legend
    CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
    // 3 - Configure legen
    theLegend.numberOfColumns = 1;
    theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    // 4 - Add legend to graph
    graph.legend = theLegend;
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorRight;
    CGFloat legendPadding = -(self.view.bounds.size.width / 8);
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(legendPadding, 0.0);
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods

- (NSString *) legendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart
                          recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx{
    return @"Legend";
}

/**
- (NSAttributedString *) attributedLegendTitleForPieChart:      (CPTPieChart *)     pieChart
                                              recordIndex:      (NSUInteger)    idxv{

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributed"];
}**/

-(NSAttributedString *)attributedLegendTitleForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    UIColor *sliceColor = [CPTPieChart defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:index].uiColor;
    UIFont *labelFont   = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0 * CPTFloat(0.5)];
#else
    NSColor *sliceColor = [CPTPieChart defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:index].nsColor;
    NSFont *labelFont   = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0 * CPTFloat(0.5)];
#endif

    NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pie Slice %lu", (unsigned long)index]];
    [title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:sliceColor
                  range:NSMakeRange(4, 5)];

    [title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                  value:labelFont
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

    return title;
}

@end
```

**Title, legend and labels won't show.**

Comment: @EricSkroch I updated my question with source code. The legend, title and label's won't show and I added a breakpoint to it but it won't trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one of those methods. Use the attributed title if you need styled text like in the example image, otherwise either method will work. These methods should be implemented in the plot's datasource.

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for the reply.. I implemented them but they fail to be called.. I updated the question with my code..

Comment: Ok solved.. I was failing to add and create a legend object and set its delegate